# Google Analytics not tracking ecommerce events from Bigcommerce

Tags: google-analytics, bigcommerce

I setup the tracking code from google in bigcommerce and the goal in google analytics. I can see the store pages in google analytics but not conversion or ecommerce data. This is the code I have in Bigcommerce. Thanks for the help!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." :"http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
try{
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-20920360-1");
pageTracker._setDomainName('.molecularrecipes.com');
pageTracker._setAllowLinker(true);
pageTracker._setAllowHash(false);
pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {}</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not seeing any ecommerce data is because you're not using the ecommerce tracking code - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncMigrationExamples#EcommerceTracking (it's under the traditional ga.js snippet dropdown.)

Also, I'd highly recommend updating your google analtics code from traditional to asynchronous, directions here - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncMigrationExamples#migrationInstructions.

And if you're feeling very adventurous, you can set yourself up for the next version of google analytics by upgrading to Universal Analytics - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thread in the Bigcommerce forum for how to add in the async code at this time. Unfortunately, we don't support the universal code at this time.

http://forum.bigcommerce.com/f33/how-to-use-async-analytics-and-get-ecommerce-tracking-8936/?highlight=async

Comment: Thank you! I am going to try this now. Should I keep these settings in google analytics? "Create a new goal in your analytics account with the follow details:
Goal URL: /finishorder.php
Goal Name: New Order for MolecularRecipes.com Store
Active Goal: On
Leave 'Define Funnel' empty
Match Type: Head Match
Goal Value: The average order value from your store
Click the 'Save' button below and Google Analytics will be integrated into your store"